# Accept only name and space in html form

Tags: html, forms, validation

I'm trying to create sign up page I want user can only enter proper name without integer or any thing
only space and character should be accept
I'm Trying This `pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,10}"`But It's Only Accepting Character, It's Not Accepting Space

Comment: What if your name is 周潤發 or Jürgen Klinsmann ... or Franz Beckenbauer (11 char surname) or your surname is double-barreled? Seriously don't even try to evaluate human names, it's a waste of time especially since you can change your name by deed poll to anything you like.

Comment: Worth a read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `blank space` to `pattern` -

```
$pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,10}";
```

Comment: Then except the answer so that other don't post their answer

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a space to your pattern:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,10}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex for your purpose
`^[a-zA-Z ]{3,10}*$`